# three.js and TrackballControls - keeping horizon flat

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm attempting to modify TrackballControls.js so that its rotation is like that of OrbitControls.js, where the horizon stays flat, but maintain the ability to rotate over and around a scene (specifically, a collada building model). I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of a day now, but I'm a designer, not a programmer. :-) I'm not even sure if I should be focusing on this.rotateCamera and/or this.update.

(BTW, I would just use OrbitControls.js, but it doesn't support panning, which is necessary when looking at large collada building models.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a work-around, you can try using `OrbitControls` and sliding the building to the right to simulate panning the camera to the left. Otherwise, it's probably easier to hack `OrbitControls` than it is to hack `TrackballControls`.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be easier to add panning to Orbit than to add level rotation to Trackball. I will see I can understand how Trackball pans and attempt to graft that into Orbit. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Yes, adding panning to `OrbitControls` would be easier, I think. Something like this: `camera.position.addSelf( delta ); controls.center.addSelf( delta );`

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since this question was asked, but I ran into the same problem and didn't find much discussion online, so I thought I'd post my solution.

If you must use TrackballControls and you want to a flat horizon, you can simply edit the TrackballControls.js library by adding the following line to the end of the 'this.rotateCamera' method

```
this.object.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
```

This locks the camera up direction in the (0,1,0) direction (i.e in the y direction). The entire modified method function would then read:

```
this.rotateCamera = function () {

    var angle = Math.acos( _rotateStart.dot( _rotateEnd ) / _rotateStart.length() / _rotateEnd.length() );

    if ( angle ) {

        var axis = ( new THREE.Vector3() ).crossVectors( _rotateStart, _rotateEnd ).normalize();
            quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

        angle *= _this.rotateSpeed;

        quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, -angle );

        _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
        _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

        _rotateEnd.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

        if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

            _rotateStart.copy( _rotateEnd );

        } else {

            quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle * ( _this.dynamicDampingFactor - 1.0 ) );
            _rotateStart.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

        }

    }

    // Lock the camera up direction
    this.object.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);

};
```

Comment: Assuming it works, do not instantiate a new object. `this.object.up.set( 0, 1, 0 );`

Comment: There has got to be a simpler way of locking the horizon.  Seems like a pretty common thing to do.